# How to get conditional input in java?

Tags: java

I want to enter two numbers CSV and CR.
The condition is that:
If CSV is Positive, CR can be Positive or Negative.
If CSV is Negative, CR cannot be Positive
So how can i do this?

Comment: What code do you have so far and what part is giving you difficulty?

Comment: What form of input are you using. Scanner, JTextField...?

Comment: I am using Scanner form

Comment: Number is a pretty abstract data type, to you mean `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("CSV: ");
double csv = scanner.nextDouble();

System.out.print("CR: ");
double cr =  scanner.nextDouble();

if (csv < 0.0) {
    while (cr > 0.0) {
        System.out.println("CR cannot be positive since CSV is negative.");
        System.out.print("CR: ");
        cr = scanner.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working...thnxx...now just one thing that i want to display the message "Invalid Input" if the above conditions are not satisfied and bring the control to end of the whole program without exiting it.. How Can i do that?